# WPF text box border changes color upon mouse entry

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox, border

For some reason my text box border is changing color to an offputting blue whenever the mouse hovers over the text box. here is my xaml:

```
 <TextBox 
   BorderThickness="1" 
   BorderBrush="Black" 
   x:Name="textBox" 
   custom:ScrollToEndBehavior.OnTextChanged="True" 
   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
   Height="154" 
   Margin="32,220,36,5" 
   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
   Text="{Binding LogText, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
   Width="449" 
   Background="WhiteSmoke" 
   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsLogVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" 
   IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the default style to black with a IsMouseOver trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                  Name="border"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                           Name="PART_ContentHost"
                           Focusable="False" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
                    Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: thank you, could you explain to me what the "Template" refers to in the Setter Property. I do not have it as an option in my intellisense drop down. I created a <Textbox.Style> tag inside of my <TextBox> and then inserted the code that you so kindly provided. And the only error that I am getting refers to the "Template"

Comment: The "Template" property allows you to overrides how your control will behave and look.